# WordPress Save Post Hidden Marker

Tags: php, wordpress

Struggling to get my head around the best way to tackle this.

In the admin of WordPress, I have a checkbox field that when it is checked, it adds a "1" value the postmeta. When this field is also checked, it adds further fields to update further postmeta. That all works fine.

However what I want is the ability for a "hidden marker" to be added, that can be checked against to the run a specific function. So I don't want the user to be able to run the function of save every time, just on the first occasion when the checkbox has been enabled and the further details added.

I will need to use this "hidden marker" for future checks and functionality to set it on or off - but in this instance I just need it to be set first time around, then no matter how many times after I save the page, that marker isn't updated and therefore the function isn't run.

Below is the rough code I am using (removed the unnecessary parts):

```
function update_recurring_fields($episode_id) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $episode_id)) return;
    if ('episode' == get_post_type()) {
        $enable_recurring = $_POST['enable_recurring'];
        $recurring_status = $_POST['recurring_status']; // THIS IS THE HIDDEN MARKER FIELD //
        if (isset($enable_recurring)) {
            update_post_meta($episode_id, 'enable_recurring', $enable_recurring); // CHECKBOX FIELD //
            update_post_meta($episode_id, 'recurring_status', '1');
        } else {
            update_post_meta($episode_id, 'enable_recurring', '0'); // CHECKBOX FIELD //
            // update_post_meta($episode_id, 'recurring_status', '');
        }
        $recurring_status_value = get_post_meta($episode_id, 'recurring_status', true); // GET RECURRING STATUS VALUE //
        if ($recurring_status_value == '1') {
            recurring_episodes_function(); // RUN FUNCTION //
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'update_recurring_fields');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Put the step that sets your hidden field inside the routine that saves the meta data. Use an if-then at the start of the routine "is field set?" No, then set it and then save the meta data. If yes, exit the save meta data routine. Use other code to unset the hidden field when user exits or on some other interaction important to your user experience.